# How to control three-tier menu logic with fixed positioning

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm trying to devise a way of managing a three-tier menu using jQuery. Each tier in the menu is a horizontal list, with subsequent tiers appearing below the preceding one. All levels in the menu have `position:"fixed"` so their position relative to one another in the HTML tree is largely irrelevant.

However, the vertical position of each tier at any one time is dependent on how many levels are visible and they will always appear to be vertically centered (their defined positions are not relative to each other) within a given area.

To illustrate, the possible configurations are as follows:

```
     ________________________________________________________________
    |                   |                        |                   |
    |                   |                        |  Level A visible  |
    |                   |     Level A visible    |                   |
    |  Level A visible  |                        |  Level B visible  |
    |                   |  Level B or C visible  |                   |
    |                   |                        |  Level C visible  |
    |___________________|________________________|___________________|
```

Despite there being three parts to the diagram above, there are essentially four states that the menu can possibly be in:

1. A level visible
2. A & B visible
3. A & C
4. A, B & C

   ```
    _______________________
   |           |           |
   |     A     |   A + B   |
   |___________|___________|
   |           |           |
   |   A + C   | A + B + C |
   |___________|___________|
   ```

What I'm struggling with is the logic that dictates how the states can be controlled. I've not used OOP before but have a feeling that it could be the right approach - although I'm not too sure how I'd start off.

I'm not expecting anyone to spoon-feed me code, but some pointers as to the "correct" approach would be great. Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem?

Comment: Maintain a `visible` boolean flag for each level, and only render that level if the associated `visible` flag is true.

Comment: Thanks, but 'm not sure I understand how this could also take the positioning into account.

Comment: If you're doing vertical centering using CSS, that should be handled automatically.  Presumably, the menu items are in a styled `div`.

Comment: Not quite in the usual way - the layout is fluid both horizontally and vertically so each tier has `position:fixed` and a percentage vertical position. i.e. I need to position each of the three levels depending on which ones are visible.